# CakePHP 2.0 Not saving

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0

So I am trying to save a form with CakePHP. Its a fairly simple form, but for some reason, an INSERT statement is never being generated.

Here is a snippet from the Controller:

```
    public function add($sid = null) {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        //The app enters here. debug($this->request->data) confirms the data is there.
        if($this->Date->save($this->request->data)) {
            //debug($this->Date->save($this->request->data)) confirms CakePHP thinks its saving the data
            //however looking at the data, and the MySQL log, an INSERT statement is never attempted.
            //The flash and redirect occur as expected.
            $this->Session->setFlash('Dates Saved!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'school', $sid));
        }
    }
    $this->set('schoolid', $sid);
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
<?php
class Date extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Date';
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->script(array(
                            'dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxcalendar.js'
                          )); 
echo $this->Html->css(array('dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxcalendar.css', 'dhtmlxCalendar/skins/dhtmlxcalendar_dhx_skyblue.css'));
?>
<div style="position:relative;height:380px;">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Dates'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('schoolid', array('value' => $schoolid, 'type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('grade', array('options' => array('5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7', '8' => '8', '9' => '9', '10' => '10', '11' => '11', '12' => '12'))); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('startreg', array('label' => 'Start Registration Date')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('endreg', array('label' => 'End Registration Date')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('lottery', array('label' => 'Lottery Date')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Dates'); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('Schools/add.js')); ?>
```

And here is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dates` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schoolid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `grade` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `startreg` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endreg` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lottery` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

If anyone has any idea why this is happening, or what debug steps I can take to try to resolve this, I would appreciate it!

Comment: what var_dump shows with this array $this->request->data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not creating your form correctly. You're attempting to create '**Dates**'. It should be '**Date**'. Give this a go:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Date'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old but for those who still land here:

Sometimes the form is submitted with PUT request automatically and $this->request->is('post') will return false.

The correct test would be:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) { ... }
```